# Is $C^1([0, 1], E)$ dense in $C([0, 1], E)$ for a general Banach-space $E$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm wondering if there is a result stating that the space of differentiable functions $C^1([0, 1], E)$ is dense in $C([0, 1], E)$ for a general Banach-space $E$. We define the derivative of a function $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow E$ simply as $$f'(t) := \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(t + h) - f(t)}{h}$$

I suspected this, since this is a Corollary from Stone-Weierstrass for $E = \mathbf{R}$. But of course one can't make generally sense of polynomials in Banach-spaces.

Comment: I have found [the notes by Hunter at UC Davis](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6A.pdf) quite useful to learn something about those "evolution spaces" (i.e., spaces of functions $I\to E$ where $E$ is a Banach space). There you can also find the approximation property you are looking for, with the same approach as David C. Ullrich's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the answer is yes. Take $f\in C([0,1],E)$. First extend $f$ to a function in $C(\Bbb R, E)$, say by making $f$ constant on $[1,\infty)$ and constant on $(-\infty,0]$. Now say $\phi_n$ is a smooth (real-valued) approximate identity; then the convolution $f*\phi_n$ should be differentiable and it should be that $f*\phi_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. The proofs of those last two assertions should be just the same as for a real-valued function $f$, seems to me...

Yes. As above, assume that $f:\Bbb R\to E$ is bounded and uniformly continuous. Say $\phi_n\ge0$, $\int \phi_n=1$, $\phi_n$ is supported in $(-1/n,1/n)$ and $\phi_n$ is continuously differentiable. Let $$f_n(x)=f*\phi_n(x)=\int f(t)\phi_n(x-t)\,dt=\int f(x-t)\phi_n(t)\,dt.$$(There are no problems with any of the integrals here or below since we're integrating continuous $E$-valued functions with compact support; in fact we could take all the integrals to be Riemann integrals...)

First, $$||f_n(x)-f(x)||=\left|\left|\int(f(x-t)-f(x))\phi_n(t)\right|\right|\le\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}||f(x-t)-f(x)||\phi_n(t)
\le\sup_{|s-t|<2/n}||f(s)-f(t)||,$$so that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\Bbb R$.

Now to show that $f_n$ is continuously differentiable. Going to write this part in a little less detail. In fact it turns out that $$f_n'=f*(\phi_n'),$$which shows that $f_n'$ is continuous by an argument like the above, since $f$ is uniformly continuous and $\phi_n'$ is integrable. Note that $$\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}=\int f(t)\frac{\phi_n(x+h-t)-\phi_n(x-t)}{h}\,dt:=\int f(t)\psi_h(x-t)\,dt$$where $$\psi_h(t)=\frac{\phi_n(t+h)-\phi_n(t)}{h}.$$The hypotheses on $\phi_n$ imply that $$\lim_{h\to0}\int|\psi_h(t)-\phi_n'(t)|\,dt=0,$$and so again, since $f$ is bounded, inequalities like the above show that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}=f*(\phi_n')(x).$$

Answer (score 3):

You can just take the coefficients of the polynomials in $E$ to have $E$-valued polynomials. Trying to mimic the Stone-Weierstraß proof for $E$-valued functions may however be tricky.

But from uniform continuity of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ you immediately get that you can uniformly approximate all functions in $C([0,1],E)$ by piecewise affine functions. A piecewise affine function has its values in a finite-dimensional subspace of $E$, so the straightforward generalisation of Stone-Weierstraß to $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued functions gives the result.

Answer (score 2):

A very elegant proof can be based on tensor product representation
$$C([0,1],E)= C([0,1]) \tilde \otimes_\varepsilon E.$$
For every dense subspace $L$ of $C([0,1])$ the tensor product $L\otimes E$ is dense.

Comment: Seems possibly interesting to note that the argument Daniel Fischer gave is a special case of this. How does one prove that that tensor product is dense? The obvious argument is to write $1=\sum_{j=1}^n\phi_j$, where $\phi_j$ is continuous and supported in a very small interval; then the uniform continuity of $f\in C([0,1],E)$ shows that $\phi_j(t)f(t)$ is uniformly close to $\phi_j(t)f(t_j)$. Now if you take the $\phi_j$ to be piecewise affine this shows that the piecewise affine functions in $C([0,1],E)$ are dense.

Comment: And then we might note that if the $\phi_j$ are translates of one function $\phi$ then the sum $\sum_jf(t_j)\phi_j(t)$ might be regarded as a discrete approximation to the convolution $\phi*f$; there's something at the bottom common to all  three posted solutions.

Comment: Having made two pointfull comments I think entitles me to make a pointless one: The reason I think the argument using convolution with an approximate identity is the "right" one is that it's _exactly_ the same as the corresponding proof that $C^1([0,1])$ is dense in $C([0,1])$. If one is proving the thing as you suggest one also has to prove the scalar-valued case first, and if one does that using an approximate identity then one is already done with the $E$-valued case! I hid the elegance in my answer by including all those details...